# Separate number with comma for thousands asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How do you do separate numbers with commas for every thousand on asp.net gridview (with c# in the back)

I have been trying the following lines (individually) in the backend(nothing works, they just cut off the decimal places)

```
row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", Convert.ToDecimal(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));
row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]).ToString("#,##0.00"); 
row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = String.Format("{0:n}", Convert.ToDecimal(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));
row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = Convert.ToDecimal(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]).ToString("N0");
```

row is a reference to the table in the database (I am looping through each object returned and going through the rows)

I have putting this where I bind to the gridview. So basically I right before it binds I change those attributes to have a comma but it doesn't do that

The lines I tried will change this

```
1092.00
```

to this

```
1092
```

but I am trying to achieve this

```
1,092
```

*** EDIT ***

This is within a template field (because I needed it to be a link with an onclick function

```html
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Applied Amount Variance">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LbPath" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum") %>'
                    CommandName="BindExpand" 
                    OnCommand="BindExpand"
                    CommandArgument='<%#Bind("Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum") %>'>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you give example input and output?

Comment: What is `row`?  Is it a row in a DataTable or a row in the GridView?

Comment: Do you want a currency?  DataFormatString="{0:c}"  This will give you a currency format.

Comment: row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = String.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToString(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));

Comment: row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToString(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IF you are looking for Currency use

```
DataFormatString="{0:c}"
```

otherwise use

```
DataFormatString="{0:N2}"
```

Try

```
    Text='<%# Eval("Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum","{0:c}") %>'
```

or

```
    Text='<%# Eval("Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum","{0:N2}") %>'
```

Comment: I am trying these two lines now (in both it doesn't change the line, so 1092.00 will turn to 1092.00)

Comment: row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = String.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToString(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));

Comment: row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"] = String.Format("{0:c}", Convert.ToString(row["Applied_Amount_Varience_Sum"]));

Comment: Have you tried these in your front end aspx <asp:BoundField      />  ??

Comment: Your edit gives "Format specifier was invalid" on this line <asp:LinkButton ID="LbPath" runat="server" (containing the text eval)

Answer (score 4):

```
private string commaSeparateNumber(string value)
{
    return String.Format("{0:#,##0}", int.Parse(value));
}
```

works for me.

in yor first line "{0:#,###0}", drop one #