# add thousand separator on string

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

i have a listView and i want a specific column has a thousand separator
i use this code but it doesnt work

```
<GridViewColumn x:Name="Fpricecolumn" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding price, StringFormat={}{0:N0}$}" Header="price" Width="180"/>
```

but its look like this

```
id      price
1       2000$
2       20000$
3       1000$
```

(i want it like this)

```
id      price
1       2,000$
2       20,000$
3       1,000$
```

i think its becuse price column in my database (which my listView bind with that) is nvarchar(string)

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572019/separate-number-with-comma-for-thousands-asp-net

Comment: That link that @DanHunex posted with enhancement for localization seems like the answer here...not sure this would totally be invariantCulture or specific, perhaps you can elaborate a bit on your question.  Note you DO need to convert to money/decimal/double etc. it would seem.

Comment: @DanHunex thank u...it works fine:)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the currency format, which will automatically include commas and will also put the `$` on the correct side:

```
StringFormat={}{0:C}}
```

You also need to make sure that your `price` field is actually a number.

Comment: @Hamid It's based on the current culture or you can pass a specific one.

Comment: @Hamid: Make sure you're actually formatting a number.