# how to right justify and format the column in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a DataTable that is created in code behind. I need to right justify the number column and I also want to bold the last column of the DataTable with a dollar sign in the beginning. I also need to put commas for the numbers. below is my cs page code:

```c#
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table");
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Title"));              
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Number));
    dt.Rows.Add("Number", 12.3);
    dt.Rows.Add("Pages", 45789);
    dt.Rows.Add("requirements", 23456);
    dt.Rows.Add("Price", 12);
    dt.Rows.Add("Property", 25);
    dt.Rows.Add("test1", 0);
    dt.Rows.Add("Total", total);
    grdCalculate.DataSource = dt;
    grdCalculate.DataBind();
```

below is my .aspx page code:

```aspx
 <asp:GridView ID="grdCalculate" runat="server" GridLines="Horizontal" CssClass="grid"></asp:GridView>
```

below is something, I want:

[image]

I want something this way so that its easier to add the columns:

```
1234.00
   1
   6
   7
   9
45609.00
```

If I apply this stylesheet:

```
 table tr td:nth-child(2)
{
    text-align:right !important;   
}
```

This is how the numbers look like:
[image]

I want something like this:

```
     14
      6
      6
  82500.00
      0
     10
     20
      0
     10
      0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET GridView - Can you right-align just one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644097/net-gridview-can-you-right-align-just-one-column)

Comment: See [Separate number with comma for thousands asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31572019/215552) for the other question in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To right justify only the second column, try the following:

```
table tr td:nth-child(2)
{
    text-align:right !important;   
}
```

You can use the same idea for first column to align in the left so it gives that space.

As for the commas, you can set the formatting like `String.Format("{0:#,##0}", value)`

Comment: This just moves the numbers to the right hand side of the grid. They are still not aligned.

Comment: I updated my answer, how does it look right now?

Comment: I updated my original post. Basically, I want the numbers to be aligned so that its easier to add. I want 6 to be right above 82500.00 before the decimal. I modified my original post so that its easier to see.

Comment: Then you can try using the same formatting for all with .00 in the end.

Comment: Is it possible to do this alignment without putting .00 at the end for all numbers. I was thinking can this be resolved using string.format

Comment: Well you can also format the string with spaces in the right like `"${value}   "` when it's a full number